# Getting TypeError when trying to destroy Chart.JS object

Tags: javascript, angular, chart.js, ng2-charts

I am developing an Angular application with a component that utilizes Chart.js to draw bar graphs from queries.

Software versioning info:

- Angular CLI: `14.2.12`
- Node: `14.21.3`
- NPM: `6.14.18`
- Chart.js: `2.9.4`
- ng2-charts: `2.4.2`

> Please note that I have to use older versions of Chart.js and ng2-charts for the platform I am deploying to.

I have added two `Chart` objects as component properties and bound them to `<canvas>` elements on my HTML template.

```
import { Chart } from "chart.js"

[. . .]

  chart1: Chart;
  chart2: Chart;
```

```html
<div id="bar-charts" class="row chart-container">
    <div class="card col-lg-6">
        <canvas id="chart1">
            {{chart1}}
        </canvas>
    </div>
   
    <div class="card col-lg-6">
        <canvas id="chart2">  
            {{chart2}}      
        </canvas>
    </div>
</div>
```

The application draws bar charts based on a query search; it can display the charts without a problem by instantiating a new `Chart` object via `new Chart("chart", { . . . } )`.

My problem arises when I want to clear existing graphs prior to making a new search query; I tried  using [Chart.js API's](https://www.chartjs.org/docs/2.9.4/developers/api.html#destroy) method `destroy()` in this custom method.

```
  private clearBarCharts(): void {
    this.chart1.destroy();
    this.chart2.destroy();
  }
```

However, calling the method generates the following `TypeError`:

```
core.mjs:6362 ERROR TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'destroy')
    at LiveDashboardComponent.clearBarCharts (live-dashboard.component.ts:433:1)
    at LiveDashboardComponent.onSubmit (live-dashboard.component.ts:108:1)
    at LiveDashboardComponent_Template_form_submit_7_listener (template.html:7:43)
    at executeListenerWithErrorHandling (core.mjs:14931:1)
    at wrapListenerIn_markDirtyAndPreventDefault (core.mjs:14972:1)
    at HTMLFormElement.eval (platform-browser.mjs:459:1)
    at _ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (zone.js:443:1)
    at Object.onInvokeTask (core.mjs:26299:1)
    at _ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (zone.js:442:1)
    at Zone.runTask (zone.js:214:1)
```

Comment: From the error, you didn't assign value to `chart1`/`chart2`. Note that you don't need the Angular expression for `{{ chart1 }}` and `{{ chart2 }}`. The moment when you create the Chart instance with `new Chart("chart", { . . . } )`, it will find the element id matching with the first argument ("chart") and render chart.

Comment: Thank you, that helped me solve my problem.